# API Forismatic JSON: Random Quote Machine

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm currently building a quote machine using forismatic API and am utterly stumped. My program was working fine until I decided to revisit my work in the future. Here's my code:

```js
var html = "http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&lang=en&format=jsonp&jsonp=?";

var getQuote=function(data){
  if(data.quoteAuthor === "") {
    data.quoteAuthor = "Unknown";
  }      
  $('#author').text(data.quoteAuthor);
  $('#text').text(data.quoteText);
  
  var quote = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + "\"" + data.quoteText + "\"" + ' Author: ' + data.quoteAuthor +' @Gil_Skates';

  $('#tweet').attr("href", quote);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON(html, getQuote, 'jsonp');
});
    
// On button click
$('#new-quote').on("click", function(){
  // Deletes text and creates spinner
  $('#text').text("");
  $('#author').text("");
  $('<span style = "margin-left:200px" class="fa-li fa fa-spinner fa-spin"/>').appendTo('#text');
  
  // Calls our random quote
  $.getJSON(html, getQuote, 'jsonp');
});

// Tweet popup
window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    t = window.twttr || {};
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 
  t._e = [];
  t.ready = function(f) {
    t._e.push(f);
  };
 
  return t;
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "quote-box centered">
  <div class = "quote-text">
      <i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i><span id = "text" >Quotes inspire<span>
  </div>
  <div class = "quote-author">
    <span id = "author">Programmer</span>
  </div>
    
  <div class = "buttons">
    <a class="button" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet" data-size="large" id="tweet" title="Tweet this now!" target="_blank">
      <i class = "fa fa-twitter"></i>
    </a>
    
    <!--<a class="button" id="tumblr" title="Share on Tumblr!" target="_blank">
      <i class = "fa fa-tumblr"></i>
    </a>-->
    
    <button class = "button" id ="new-quote">New Quote</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? I've created a variable to hold my url, created a function that gets the data, and used the getJSON to utilize my function. (Excuse my terminology)

It works when I run it on this website, but on: https://codepen.io/gilioo/pen/JKpjgr
it doesn't generate a quote.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I edited your question to include jQuery in your code snippet (I made *no* other change) and now your code works as you can see by clicking "Run code snippet". If the real problem is more than that, please [edit] your question to explain what the problem is. What is the expected behaviour, and what is the actual behaviour? Do you get any errors in the browser's console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's a Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) issue, you're accessing codepen.io via https but the forismatic API is only offered via http afaik.
You could try http://codepen.io and see if it works. I've run into the same issue myself when trying to use the API via https.

Comment: Adding https://crossorigin.me/ before the the forismatic URL worked for me if you're still having trouble.